# Getting an error when trying to create a tarball of my Redhat VM

Tags: unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tar

I'd appreciate some assistance as to where I'm going wrong please.

Ultimately my objective is to have Redhat available via Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Reading the instructions on the following website ....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/use-custom-distro

Apparently you can import a tarball of any OS that you create, so with that in mind I created a Redhat 9.1 VM via HyperV and intended to tar the contents up.

I initially tried this command "tar -cvf /rh9.tar *" (I know if this command had worked I may have ended up with a recursion type error where it tried to add itself to the archive) but it didn't work and I ended up getting an error similar to this one:

```
tar: /mnt/rh9.tar: Wrote only 6144 of 10240 bytes
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I then created a virtual disk of 500Gb and mounted it under /mnt and tried again - and received the error I showed above, however this time I used the following command:

```
tar -cvf /mnt/rh9.tar -exclude /mnt /
```

Looking at the file in /mnt it is basically nearly 500Gb large, but I can't understand how this can be as when I do a "df -h" I see the following:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  731M  8.9M  722M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   70G  4.4G   66G   7% /
/dev/sdb2             1014M  277M  738M  28% /boot
/dev/sdb1              599M  7.0M  592M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rhel-home   52G  413M   52G   1% /home
tmpfs                  366M   36K  366M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Adding up all the disk space in use results in a number well less than the 500Gb - can anyone give some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

This method is advised in the post
[How would I use tar for full backup and restore with system on SSD and home on HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524418/how-would-i-use-tar-for-full-backup-and-restore-with-system-on-ssd-and-home-on-h)

```
sudo su
cd /
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system / 
tar -cvpzf backuphome.tar.gz --one-file-system /home/
```

The second command is to be used if `home` is on a different partition
than root.

Note that the backup file is excluded, in order to avoid looping.

Comment: Close, but that's still going to create two different tarballs.  And WSL only allows you to use *one* as the source for a distribution.  Probably better to use [`--append`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/appending-files.html), but I haven't tried it.  I *think* you'll also need to use a straight tar, rather than gzipped, for `--append` to work.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I would imagine since the second command is only required if `home` is on a different partition than root, then you can simply combine the two commands and change `--one-file-system /` to `--one-file-system /home/`